# Can i change my windows password on a remote machine (without signing in)?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, passwords

I have a problem:
I asked one of my customers to please reset my password. The customer did that, but with the usally "change password on first logon" flag.
This in turn leads to the problem that I can't authenticate over MSTSC, because MSTSC is telling me that I should please change the password bevor the first logon...
Now I was just wondering, if there is any way to change the password without driving to the customers location or asking him to remove the flag.
Something like a powershell call or similiar...

Comment: I tried some googling but could not find the right keywords to get any usefull Information so far.

Comment: you could try connecting to the console by using the /admin flag. it might allow you to change the password then, but couldn't test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Powershell is just a local shell. To make a change in a remote system you need to be able to access it first, which means you need to be able to login...

I would personally just call the customer, tell him about the funny little mishap that requires you to login before you can change your password to login, have a ha-ha together and ask him to please reset it again but without the "change at next login" -flag. I mean this doesn't sound like you made a mistake.

This is how good anecdotes are made :-)

Comment: Not true. If the firewall ports are open and the remote system is inside the network, you can use `enter-pssession` similarly as you can use psexec to execute cmd commands over a network.

Comment: That's a good point. But are the ports open? Considering "... driving to the customer's location..." I'd say in this case it's clear we aren't inside the network. But thanks - I just learned something new :-)

Comment: Sadly peregrino69 is right, no open ports for me :)
I was just thinking, well this does sound like something you could maybe do over a programming interface since it does not sound like a very rar case (had that already quiet a lot but never though about the interface...)